# Why is my for loop running only 2 times instead of 10?

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the third highest number in the array with O(n) space and time complexity.
MY program is obviously wrong but that is not the problem.
My for loop in the `thirdhighestnum` function seem to running only 2 times. I can't seem to find the reason for it. Can anyone help me. Sorry for such basic question I am a beginner here.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int thirdhighestnum(int a[],int size)
{ 
    cout<<" "<<size<<endl;
    int first=a[0],second=0,third=0;
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<";"<<endl;
        if(a[i]>first)
        {
            first=a[i]; 
            if(a[i+1]>first)
            {
                second=first;
                first=a[i+1];
                if(a[i+2]>first)
                {   third=second;
                    second=first;   
                    first=a[i+2];

                }
            }
            cout<<i<<endl
            return third;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{  int num,a[10];
    cout<<"Enter the elements in the array"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    cout<<"Third highest number is "<<thirdhighestnum(a,10)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, please, *please*, read up on [Clang Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) *now*! And start using it. The formatting of this code is atrocious and close to un-readable. Please fix. (Better after the edit)

Comment: You seem to be missing a semicolon just before `return third` in `thirdhighestnum`. Is this also the case in your local copy?

Comment: I fixed that but its still running only 2 times

Comment: other than missing a semicolon. You for loop is running 9 times. There is no problem there

Comment: @Glorious15 give the test case you are entering

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `a[i + 1]` and `a[i + 2]` are red flags since you have the potential to go past the end of your array.

Comment: Well indexing off *could* cause it---it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Glorious15 i entered `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0` and it is running fine 9 times, do check once again

Comment: @HimanshuSingh when I entered 9 8 7 6  5 4 3 2 1 0 loop works perfects but when I enter 1 2  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 it only runs 2 times

Comment: @Glorious15 it looks like you're just prematurely returning from your function. Is `return third` intended to be inside of the loop?

Comment: A co-worker of mine wrote up a nice blog post [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You've initialized `a[10]` i.e. a[0] up to a[9] can be accessed, Your a[i] with i == 10 is out of bounds. So there is undefined behavior (stack overflow!). So you have to start not with 1 but with 0 in the loop!
Also a[i+1] and a[i+2] points outside of the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's the location of your `return third` statement. The moment any number is larger than the first number, it exits the `thirdhighestnum` function and returns a value. Put it outside your `for` loop and it should be fine.

Comment: Note that this doesn't address issues with array indexing that (could) still lead to incorrectness.

Comment: This is true, my answer is not comprehensive but it just covers the first hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) and library function can do this for you.
As for why your code fails, there is a flaw in your logic

```
for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
{
    // some code
    if(a[i]>first)
    {
        // some more code
        cout<<i<<endl
        return third;
    }
}
```

So your code exits the first time a[i] is greater than first.

[edit - After reading comments]
The generic name for this type of algorithm is a [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). It is unlikely you will find a faster algorithm, as this has been the subject of years of academic study.

Comment: `nth_element` from `algorithm` is actually O(n log n). The question specifically states they're looking for an O(n) solution.

Comment: "O(N) applications of the predicate, and O(N log N) swaps", but I see what you mean.

Comment: @kop: In all fairness, the OP's code doesn't run in O(n) either. And that's already ignoring all those out-of-bounds array accesses. Now, in the vast majority of cases where a developer - especially a beginner - asks to have their raw loop fixed, the answer is to replace it with a pre-built algorithm.

Comment: @IInspectable fair enough, but providing a O(n log n) algorithm when the question asks about an O(n) one (without making a note of the time complexity in the answer itself) doesn't really sit well with me and while I agree that a perhaps a *better* solution to this problem (cf. the question posed) is a standardised algorithm, there is some value in beginners writing code like what an improved version of OPs would look like (say, with less UB).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is executing only **one** time i.e. the first iteration only. When `i=1` then it prints a[1] i.e. `2;` after that it prints `i` i.e. `1` so it appears as `2;1` here you think it is printing `2` numbers.

The main problem is your `return third` statement which terminates your for loop in first iteration only.